# DialogResult could not be Found C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam using this code.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //...
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
```

It throws me an error:

***The type of namespace name 'DialogResult' could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an essembly reference?)***

How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you have added `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged your question with `asp.net` and what you are trying to do is not possible in `asp.net`, you can choose the alternative of doing this by using `Javascript`, put the `JS` code in whatever event handler you are using. If you are using on some button click handler then put this one on your `OnClientClick`

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to Save changes?');"
```

It will return true if user click on OK and false if clicks on Cancel.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of a MessageBox is a MessageBoxResult, not DialogResult.
(DialogResult is for older, like FileOpen Dialogs). Change "DialogResult" in your code to "MessageBoxResult", and it will rub.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to your project as well as `import System.Windows.Forms` in your source?